# Gravity form gform_after_submission is not working

Tags: gravity-forms-plugin

I am trying to submit the form data to a third party on successful submission of gravity form. But I am stuck at the first stage. Looks like the function is not running or may be something wrong with my code. Here is my code:

```
add_action( 'gform_after_submission_8', 'post_to_third_party', 10, 2 );
function post_to_third_party( $entry, $form ) {
    $body = array(
        'name' => rgar( $entry, '1' ), 
        'email' => rgar( $entry, '2' ), 
        'phone' => rgar( $entry, '3' ),
        'case_details' => rgar( $entry, '4' ),
        );
    print_r($body);
}
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: in addition, it just shows up the blank page and do not echo or print anything.

Comment: Check your error_log file. Try to write to a log file with `error_log()` instead of `print_r()`.  Remove unneeded last comma after `'4' )`.

Comment: Ok I will check and will post back if any issues or resolved.